# How to create multiline texbox with default text in mvc 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to create a `multiline textbox` with SQL query as a default text. I am able to create a normal `textbox` with predefined, text but not able to do the same for `multiline textbox`.

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

As always you could start with a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Then a controller action that will populate this view model and pass it to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Text = ... go fetch from your db
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally a strongly typed view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Text)
}
```

This will render a corresponding `<textarea>` HTML element (or as you call it multiline textbox). By exploring the various overloads of the `TextAreaFor` helper you could control the number of rows and columns.

Comment: Thanks @darin, tried in above way, still rendering empty textbox.

Comment: Well then I guess you did something differently. Because when I tested this code it worked perfectly fine. Unfortunately it's hard to tell what you might have done differently without you showing what you have actually done.

Comment: Thanks @darin, Issue solved with above code, i did some internal mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you can also manipulate this `@Html.TextAreaFor` helper.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Text, 10, 40, null);
```

10 is for rows,
40 is for columns